# Lotus notes picklist auto positioning

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

In lotus notes 6.5.6 i want to do this:

select one document in a view and then i run an agent that show me a view(with *picklist method*) and I want the cursor **should reach on a specific view entry based on and original's selected document field**. it's possible ?

i know this is possible with *prompt method* specifying the 'default' parameter but i can't use this method because i have to propose a view and not a list of values.... it's possible to do this ? I want to see all entry in the view so i can't use SingleCategory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible, not even in Version 9 (that is a little newer than your Version from 2008).

You might be successfull by using the API to send keystrokes, but as you do not have an event that fires when the Picklist- Window opens it is very unlikely that you could place the keystroke- sending code anywhere.